# gillnets/gillnetfit error: Non-numeric argument… invalid type (list) for variable…

Tags: r

When I run the code I get the error:

> Error in lens * msizes : non-numeric argument to binary operator.

Here are links to an overview of the code package I am using and the actual code (Function for gillnet data analyses code only): https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~millar/selectware/R/gillnets/gillnetfunctions.pdf (overview), https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~millar/selectware/R/gillnets/gillnetfunctions.R (code I am using).

Below is the data set, The first column must contain the length classes. The second and subsequent columns contain the numbers caught in the different sized meshes used. These columns are in order of increasing mesh size. Next comes the code for vector data for the mesh sizes. Then my actual code for the function. Packages active while running are magrittr, dplyr, tidyr, plotrix, lattice, FSA, tidyverse, glm2, and msm. After completing the gillnetfit function I run the equation below and it returns this error:

> Error in lens * msizes : non-numeric argument to binary operator.

I have used multiple equations from the overview page, it returns the same error

Data set (AKA svcp2 in the input code):

```
svcp2 <- structure(list(Length_bin = c(450L, 575L, 600L, 625L, 650L, 675L, 
700L, 725L, 750L, 775L, 800L, 825L, 850L, 875L, 900L, 925L, 950L, 
975L, 1000L, 1025L, 1050L, 1150L), X3.00 = c(0L, 8L, 11L, 13L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L), X4.00 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 10L, 19L, 
35L, 42L, 45L, 40L, 27L, 24L, 10L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L), X4.25 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 11L, 28L, 46L, 52L, 53L, 39L, 31L, 
23L, 9L, 8L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), X4.50 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), X5.00 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 11L, 
15L, 23L, 27L, 28L, 21L, 19L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -22L))
```

Mesh size vector

```
meshsizes <- c(3, 4, 4.25, 4.5, 5)
```

Functions must be sourced from [here](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~millar/selectware/R/gillnets/gillnetfunctions.R). Do eg.

```
source("https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~millar/selectware/R/gillnets/gillnetfunctions.R")
```

Final equation used that returns error

```
gillnetfit(svcp2, meshsizes)
```

Comment: there's nothing inherently wrong with this question, but digging through a wall of code is likely to deter a lot of potential answerers ... is there any chance you can boil this down to a more compact question?

Comment: Voting to close. Seems pretty clear from inspection that you have not provided enough data and code to construct a [MCVE]

Comment: I can't reproduce your error with the data you supplied. Post the result of `dput(holt.dat)`, so that we get an exact representation of your data. My hunch is that one or more of the columns in `holt.dat` isn't numeric, but that's about all I can say.

Comment: thanks, I re-entered my data and I am not getting that error code anymore

Comment: this is the final step of the code I used instead of the other gillnetfit(svcp2,meshsizes)

Comment: Getting this error now Error in model.frame.default(formula = dat ~ -1 + var1 + var2 + as.factor(lens),  : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'dat'
6. model.frame.default(formula = dat ~ -1 + var1 + var2 + as.factor(lens), 
    drop.unused.levels = TRUE) 
5. stats::model.frame(formula = dat ~ -1 + var1 + var2 + as.factor(lens), 
    drop.unused.levels = TRUE) 
4. eval(mf, parent.frame()) 
3. eval(mf, parent.frame()) 
2. glm(dat ~ -1 + var1 + var2 + as.factor(lens), family = poisson) 
1. gillnetfit(svcp, meshsizes)

Comment: Could you do `dput(holt.dat)`, please?

Comment: My equivalent to holt.dat is svcp2. Added dput(svcp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `svcp2` is a data.frame.
As per the documentation you linked to it needs to be a matrix, although the docs and the code doesn't appear to be in complete sync. In the code the first argument is called `svcp2` while in the docs it's called `data`, but the meaning is still clear.

> data — Matrix containing the catch data…
>   https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~millar/selectware/R/gillnets/gillnetfunctions.pdf

The solution is thus simply

```
gillnetfit(as.matrix(svcp2), meshsizes)
```

Comment: I would like to say thank you very much for helping me with this. I really appreciate it. That being said it is now throwing a new error code:`Error in rcurves(type, meshsizes, rel, pars, plotlens) :
  could not find function "rcurves"`                                                                                                   This code was last updated in 2009, so I am wondering if it is part of an old package

Comment: @fishy_stats: You need all the functions in https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~millar/selectware/R/gillnets/gillnetfunctions.R. Either load them as you did with `gillfits()`, or use `source()` as I edited into your question.

Comment: Oh my god it works. It really works! Thank you so much, you have no idea how happy I am. I am so incredibly grateful for your help. I've only been coding for about a month, thank you so much for your patience and help.